# string::insert produces a runtime error

Tags: c++

I have a string b, I want to reverse it, then append the result to a string a. I tried this but It gives me a runtime error

```
a.insert(a.end(), b.rbegin(), b.rend())
```

which is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
```

What's the problem with my line of code ?

UPDATE : Here is a very short program that throws the same exception :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


    int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
        string result="bbb";
        string tail="aaa";
        result.insert(result.end(), tail.rend(), tail.rbegin());
        cout << result << endl;
        return 0;

    }
```

I am using GCC 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: Can you give use a little bit more code. A [mcve], perhaps?

Comment: [It should work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/850c06f746a0efdd)

Comment: @Borgleader I know, but my complete example fails on that website too, which is kinda reassuring !

Comment: Shouldn't it be `result.insert(result.end(), tail.rbegin(), tail.rend());`

Comment: Sorry that was so stupid of me, I mixed rbegin and rend in my program, and put them in the right order when I asked the question...

Answer (score -3):

The "insert" you're using doesn't work because:

Inserts characters from the range [first, last) before the element pointed by pos. This overload does not participate in overload resolution if InputIt does not satisfy InputIterator. (since C++11)

The begin() of a can't get a valid pos. For this case, you can use append instead:

a.append(b.rbegin(), b.rend());

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using insert in this way, other than the fact that the range to be copied was passed in backwards. In particular, inserting at `end()` works just fine; it's equivalent to `append`.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, after puting rend and rbegin in the right order I have no more errors.